# Копирование файлов

Tags: windows, unix

Я работаю на Windows, но код запускаю на удаленых никсах. Обычно копировал файлы через Winscp. Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть альтернативные способы залить файлы на удаленную машину?

Answer (score 1):

да куча, тот же фтп, scp ( кстати чем вас Winscp не устраивает ? ) samba, vpn + samba ...

Answer (score 1):

rsync под cygwin. Достаточно один раз написать простенький скрипт. Плюс копируется только то, что действительно изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, sshfs. Дёшево и сердито.

Comment: sshfs реализована для Unix-систем. Как вы предлагаете использовать ее под Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант используйте ftp или svn, можно через cifs(smb), у putty есть инструмент для пересылки файлов через ssh. Можно организовать обратный доступ - сделать на винде шару и подмонтировать ее куда вам там надо в unix'ах. Я не представляю что вам лучше подходит т.к. никогда подобным не занимался.