# Как подключиться по FTP к серверу убунту, если подключение происходи по RSA ключу?

Tags: ubuntu, веб-сервер, ftp, digitalocean, сеть

Есть сервер на ubuntu 16.04 на DigitalOcean. Подключаюсь по ssh с помощью такой команды:

```
ssh -i configs/algo.pem root@168.68.76.135
```

В файле algo.pem лежит RSA PRIVATE KEY.

Как подключиться к серверу по FTP в этом случае(то есть я как бы не знаю логин/пароль, есть только RSA ключ)? Можно ли подключаться по FTP для передачи файлов в консоле? А как подключиться через FTP клиент, например, Transmit или Commander One ?

Comment: Любой нормальный клиент имеет возможность подключения по ключу. Например, Filezilla. Читайте документацию, там все написано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить ftp доступ к сайту на сервере, если есть ssh доступ к нему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445639/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-ftp-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-ssh-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: ну и ещё для разнообразия: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12972/178576

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас там вообще ftp-сервер есть?
Я бы на вашем месте вначале зашел туда по ssh и посмотрел, а что там вообще настроено...